# Where are the definitions for methods in nativescript docs

Tags: nativescript, code-documentation

This is a (hopefully) rather simple question. In the nativescript documentation, the method definitions always say something like *"Defined in ui/core/view-base/view-base.d.ts:301"*, but I have no clue what that's referring to and I need to know what these methods do. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place or the wrong docs? I'm learning to use nativescript so any help would be great!

Thanks

This is the documentation I'm trying to use: https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is all there is for now; it just shows you it takes a ViewBase parameter, it returns nothing and it unloads the View.
But, on the bright side, a core team member, Alex Zisking announced recently on Twitter that for the 8.0 release (planned for 8.0 planned ~ Q1 of 2021) the documentation will be rewritten.